# Prove equation with $x$, $y$, $r$ definition.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that
$$\frac{\csc\theta}{\tan\theta+\cot\theta}=\cos\theta$$
by expressing each function in terms of its $x$, $y$, and $r$ definition.

Comment: $$\frac{\csc x}{\tan x+\cot x}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}$$

Comment: Please watch your parentheses.  Your equation is false as written.  You need the $\tan$ and the $\cot$ to be in the denominator on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\csc\theta=\frac{r}{y}$, $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}$, and $\cot\theta=\frac{x}{y}$.  (What about $\cos\theta$?  Do you know its representation in terms of $x$, $y$, and $r$?)

Start at one end of the equation; the left-hand side is more "complicated" so it's better to start there.  Replace the trigonometric terms with their corresponding equivalent forms in $x$, $y$, and $r$.

$$\frac{\csc\theta}{\tan\theta+\cot\theta}=\frac{\frac{r}{y}}{\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}}$$

Simplify by multiplying the expression by $\frac{xy}{xy}$:

$$\frac{rx}{y^2+x^2}$$

Then use the identity $x^2+y^2=r^2$.  You should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Got it, thanks.